# Non-integer primary key Rails indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Got a legacy database with a table Content::Translation which has columns `text`, `resource_id` and `ayah_key`

`resource_id` = integer,
`ayah_key` = string

My model:

```
class Content::Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend Content

    self.table_name = 'translation'
    self.primary_keys = :ayah_key, :resource_id
end
```

When indexing with Elasticsearch, it creates a batch query of 1000 which creates PSQL errors:

```
SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "content"."translation"  WHERE ("content"."translation"."ayah_key" >= 0) AND ("content"."translation"."resource_id" >= 0) LIMIT 1000) subquery_for_count
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text >= integer
LINE 1: ...ation"  WHERE ("content"."translation"."ayah_key" >= 0) AND ...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "content"."translation"  WHERE ("content"."translation"."ayah_key" >= 0) AND ("content"."translation"."resource_id" >= 0) LIMIT 1000) subquery_for_count
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text >= integer
LINE 1: ...ation"  WHERE ("content"."translation"."ayah_key" >= 0) AND ...
```

This is due to my ayah_key column being a string, and I do need that column to be a string. Is there a way where I can write a scope or do something so that it compares to perhaps `>= '0'` ?

Answer (score 1):

How about a method for it and then use that as the attribute?

```
def ayah_key_id
  ayah_key.to_i
end
```

Comment: How would I do that? Also, the string's anatomy is such: `number:number` eg: `1:12`

Comment: do you mean you want `def ayah_composite ayak_key_id.to_s + resource_id.to_s end` or something.  Not clear what you want.

Comment: Posted my answer! Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

This gem solved it for me that allows for non-integer `find_each` and `find_in_batches`

https://github.com/mojotech/batchelor